# What does it mean to describe a movie as "perennial favorite"?

Tags: meaning

I have seen the word used to describe the movie "Bringing Up Baby" in a review on IMDB.

> Howard Hawks, the director of "Bringing Up Baby", was not a name one associates with screwball comedy. Watching this perennial favorite the other night, one wishes Mr. Hawks would have made more comedies like this one because he shows a tremendous capacity for entertaining his audiences.

Now, I wouldn't have given it that much thinking if it wasn't used in an example sentence by Cambridge Dictionary.

[The film "White Christmas" is a perennial favourite.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/perennial)

Does it mean my "all-time favorite" movie?

Comment: When you looked up *perennial* in Cambridge, what did it tell you the word meant?

Comment: Hint:  Was the review perhaps referencing a holiday-themed movie, that would be shown almost exclusively on or near that holiday, *every year*?

Comment: @DanBron I have edited the question and added more details.

Comment: @cobaltduck No. I added a part of the review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed straight from the definition of perennial: enduring, persistent, and timeless would be proper synonyms. "All-time favorite" really would not.

When used by movie reviewers, perennial favorite is a sort of industry term for a film with long-lasting appeal to audiences; it is still beloved even after much time has elapsed. Examples of perennial favorites in our day and age might include *Star Wars*, *The Wizard of Oz*, or *Princess Bride*, whereas *Citizen Kane*, though perhaps a perennial favorite of movie critics, tends not to be seen as a perennial favorite of audiences.